# Casting for nullable fields from database

Tags: c#, ado.net

When working with nullable fields, what's the recommended statement?

Those four assignments seems to work fine, I was just wondering which statement I should use.

```
DataRow detailRow;
...
int? field = detailRow["fieldName"] == DbNull.Value ? default(int?) : (int)detailRow["fieldName"];
int? field = (int?)detailRow["fieldName"];
int? field = Int32.TryParse(detailRow["fieldName"] as String, out var parsedInt) ? parsedInt : default(int?)
int? field = detailRow.Field<int?>("fieldName"); //Field is a extension from System.Data
```

Comment: I would use the first one since it can be made generic `nullable<T>` and work with all value types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Data;

...

int? field = detailRow.Field<int?>("fieldName");
```

use the `.Field` Extension https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you know the datatype of that column is `int?` (or any other nullable type), you can go with the following:

```
int? field = detailRow["fieldName"] as int?;
```

The code is short, readable and self explanatory. In case the column contains anything other than `int?` it will assign `NULL` anyways.